# JS reduce() method syntax understanding

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following two codes one could run from any browser.

Code1:

```
let prices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let result = prices.reduce( (x,y)=>{x+y} ); // Reduce data from x to y.
console.log(result);
```

Code2:

```
let prices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let result = prices.reduce( (x,y)=>x+y ); // Reduce data from x to y.
console.log(result);
```

The first code doesn't work but the second does.

Why would the braces (`{}`) make it not to work? Aren't they part of an implicit function? Or this **braceless** syntax is just something unique to the `reduce()` method?

Comment: You need to explicitly mention 'return'.

Please refer to 'Function Body' & 'Returning object literals' sections to understand more about arrow functions.

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first one the `return` statement is missing:

```
let prices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let result = prices.reduce( (x,y)=>{return x+y;} ); // Reduce data from x to y.
console.log(result);
```

In the second example `return` is implicit.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Why do we need the `return` in the explicit versioon in the first place? I rarely use `return` in JS, only when I want to stop a function in a certain place in its scope, and move on to the next part of my code.

Comment: Because the `reduce` function needs it. In every iteration you need to return the next accumulator, which then will be the first argument for the following iteration.

Answer (score 3):

The first doesn't work because the `{}` are present. In ES6 the `=>` can serve as a replacement for the `return` keyword if the next thing following the `=>` is without `{}`.

In the case where the `{}` is supplied after the `=>` you'd need to explicitly use the `return` keyword.

In code 1, you'd need to modify it slightly like below:

```
let prices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let result = prices.reduce( (x, y) => { return x + y }); // Note the return keyword
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

The second example works because *without* the braces, `x+y` is returned implicitly.  If you include the braces, you must *explicitly* return the value, e.g. `{return x+y}`

Comment: The real tragedy is that `() => {}` does not return an object.

Comment: The issue is that braces are over-loaded -- they can either be used for function bodies, or object literals.  It only makes sense that for arrow functions they must be interpreted as function bodies, because not all arrow functions will just return a value, but might contain other statements as well.

Comment: I upvoted it. I was just making a comment